# Simple Injector fallback to Xamarin Forms DependencyService

Tags: xamarin.forms, simple-injector

I'm looking for a way that I can get Simple Injector to locate services registered with the Xamarin Forms Dependency Service, when the services cannot otherwise be resolved by the Container. Is there a way to do this with Simple Injector?

Comment: Can you improve your question and elaborate more on how you need to locate services registered with the Xamarin Forms Dependency Serbice and why these serves cannot otherwise be resolve by the Container?

Comment: @Steven With Unity I can add a Builder Strategy or with DryIoc I can add a rule so that when the container is unable to locate say `IMyService` it will try to locate the service by making a call to `Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IMyService>()`. Is there a way to accomplish this with Simple Injector so that when the container cannot locate the service, I can provide it a backup way to locate the services?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely possible with Simple Injector. But I do like to know why you don't want Simple Injector to build up those services. It seems to are using 2 containers to build up your application components, which is typically a bad idea, because you will blind your container, which is unable to provide you with any useful diagnostics about your configuration.

Comment: @Steven the goal is to use it as a fallback strategy, to be used as a last ditch effort to locate a service that wasn't registered before throwing any errors. There could be a variety of reasons for this: The Container is in a PCL and simply cannot directly access the Platform. We could be using a Xamarin Forms service with a platform implementation that has an internal access modifier preventing us from getting the implementation directly, etc...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't sound like a valid reason for doing this fallback. Your container should be wired in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) which is part of the startup path of the end application. At this point you have a reference to all assemblies and should be able to register all components. Falling back seems like failing silently to me. You don't want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unregistered type resolution can be implemented using the [`Container.ResolveUnregisteredType` event](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#unregistered-type-resolution).

Do note however that you should take my warnings as stated in the comments very seriously. Your scenario is *not* a good case for unregistered type resolution.

Comment: +1 for the comments. Failing silently should be prevented no matter what and using Xamarin DependencyService is Service Location and thus shouldn't be used also!